# Group by statement causing nested loops in the Oracle execution plan

Tags: oracle, query-performance

I have a query which has joins the results of 3 sub queries and perform a group by on the result set. The result set from the join of 3 sub queries is faster and returning 10 million rows in almost 1 min.

However when i Introduce the group by on the result set, the query performance is terrible. I see nested loops in the query plan. Can someone recommend any suggestions on how to improve the query performance.

Comment: We need to see the query and the execution plan before we can help you.

Comment: Also, "10 million rows in 1 minute" doesn't sound good...